# ia32-libs will not install due to dependency problems

Tags: 12.04, multiarch

When I upgraded to 12.04 all the 32bit libraries was removed. 
When I used Synaptic to upgrade, Synaptic installed all the 32bit libraries.
When I later used apt-get to install a ppa, I was told to use autoremove to remove all the 32bit libraries, which I did.

After this Synaptic wanted to install the libraries again, but now I marked ia32-libs forinstead.
The installation works fine, but I am not able to install Skype as Skype depeneds on ia32-libs.

When I try to install ia32-libs, I get this error printout

> ia32-libs:
>   Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch

Comment: That would be a big problem also for running Wolfram research CDF player on Linux. Since ia32-libs are needed to run the player!

Comment: I don't use Skype, but can you try installing the 32 bit package of Skype? I also uninstalled ia32-libs, so I could not install the 64 bit version of Google Earth, but the 32 bit package worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing [ia32-libs-multiarch [image: Install ia32-libs-multiarch]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ia32-libs-multiarch)? If you get any more dependency issues, install those as well.

Comment: That was the first I thought of, but when I look in Synaptic there is no ia32-libs-multiarch available.
I also tried to download and install ia32-libs-multiarch, but that did not work either.

However I just found a solution in the archived Precise development forum.
Skype works if you install the 32-bit version instead of the 64-bit version on a 64-bit installation of 12.04

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge ia32-libs
sudo apt-get install librtmp0/precise
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that those packages are missing on the mirror that you are using.

You could consider switching to a different mirror which hopefully has a more up to date package list.

Comment: Why would some Ubuntu mirrors not have these packages?

Comment: It's possible that a non-default mirror didn't sync entirely with the main server which is being used.